# Python - Property and updating attribute values

Tags: python, properties, attributes

I'm currently trying to wrap my head around Python properties.

Suppose I am to convert between Celsius and Kelvin. I have a class Degrees, that handles these calculations:

```
class Degrees(object):

    def __init__(self, celsius):
        self.celsius = celsius

    #Celsius
    def set_celsius(self, celsius):
        self._celsius = celsius
    def get_celsius(self):
        return self._celsius
    celsius = property(fget=get_celsius, fset=set_celsius)

    #Kelvin
    def set_kelvin(self, kelvin):
        self._kelvin = kelvin
    def get_kelvin(self):
        return self._kelvin
    kelvin = property(fget=get_kelvin, fset=set_kelvin)

    def to_kelvin(self):
        self.kelvin = self.celsius + 273.15
        return self.kelvin

    def to_celcius(self):
        self.celsius = self.kelvin - 273.15
        return self.celsius
```

Then, I use the following:

```
deg = Degrees(20) #Set celsius to 20
print ("In Kelvin {0:.3f}.").format(deg.to_kelvin()) #Works
deg.kelvin = 300 #Should alter celsius
print ("New celsius {0}").format(deg.celsius)
```

The output:

```
>>>> New celsius 20
```

For the last print I expect 26.850 (the new Celsius value). Instead, I get 20 (the old). That is, the value celsius has not been updated.

How can I solve this? Any pointers are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't store two separate attributes that depend on each other. They are bound to get out of sync. Instead, pick a canonical value to store, and convert to and fro. Since you start with celcius, it probably makes sense to use that throughout.

```
class Degrees(object):

    def __init__(self, celsius):
        self._celsius = celsius

    #Celsius
    def set_celsius(self, celsius):
        self._celsius = celsius
    def get_celsius(self):
        return self._celsius
    celsius = property(fget=get_celsius, fset=set_celsius)

    #Kelvin
    def set_kelvin(self, kelvin):
        self._celsius = self.to_celsius(kelvin)
    def get_kelvin(self):
        return self.to_kelvin(self._celsius)
    kelvin = property(fget=get_kelvin, fset=set_kelvin)

    def to_kelvin(self, celsius):
        return celsius + 273.15

    def to_celsius(self, kelvin):
        return kelvin - 273.15
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `set_kelvin` function to -

```
def set_kelvin(self, kelvin):
    self._kelvin = kelvin
    self._celsius = self.to_celcius()
```